# Guice: Different bindings in test and subproject

Tags: java, maven, guice

I have a maven project `javaruntime` and a maven project `androidruntime` which depends on the `javaruntime` project.
Each of the projects has a Guice-Module binding some classes to Interfaces.

In the `javaruntime` is an Interface `IElementFactory` and a Class `C` which gets the `IElementFactory` by constructor injection:

```
public class C {
    @Inject
    public C(IElementFactory factory, ...(other interfaces)...) {...}
    // ...
}
```

The concrete Implementation for the `IElementFactory` is in the `androidruntime` project and called `AndroidElementFactory`. All implementations of the other interfaces are within the `javaruntime`.

In the `javaruntime` I have JUnit-tests which should use a `MockElementFactory` because it does not know the `androidruntime`.

If I bind the `IElementFactrory` to the `AndroidElementFactory` only in the `androidruntime` Module, the Tests fail of course, because no implementation is bound for that interface within the `javaruntime` Module/project.

If I then bind the `MockElementFactory` in the `javaruntime` Module the tests are fine, but then I cannot compile the `androidruntime` because the IElementFactory is already bound to the `MockElementFactory` and overriding a binding is bad and not reommended in Guice.

But how can I accomplish that the Mock is used for the test and in the android-project it is still possible to bind the correct implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, in fact you don't want to do that. When you're unit testing your class, especially with mocks, you shouldn't use Guice. Instead you should instantiate your class directly, providing all its dependencies to it. Since you're writing *unit* test this should not be a problem, since all its dependencies in the test should be trivial or be mocked.

But if you *really* want to do what you intend to do, you have to split your program into several modules. For simplicity, let them be `MainModule`, `MockModule` and `AndroidModule`. In `MainModule` you configure all your bindings except for `IElementFactory`. It can look like this:

```
public class MainModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // Require presence of IElementFactory
        requireBinding(IElementFactory.class);

        // Bind all other dependencies
        ...
    }
}
```

And in your `MockModule` and `AndroidModule` you bind corresponding implementations of `IElementFactory`.

Then in your tests you create your injector like this:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule(), new MockModule());
```

and in android project you create it like this:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule(), new AndroidModule());
```

If you cannot do this because injector instantiation is hardcoded, then you should really consider refactoring your program because it is not how Guice projects are structured, especially wrt. unit tests. I cannot say more because you haven't explained exact structure of your program.

Comment: great, thanks for the solution approach and especially for discussing an alternative and the better practice!

Comment: Completely agree with the instantiate with Mock parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the above solution ideas. I, however, have to disagree with the statement that you should not use Guice in your unit tests.  :-) I have a specific case where I need to test that my Guice bindings are correct on some java source files that I code generate via a java annotation processor that I built..  I also want to be able to override some service bindings so that my tests run in isolation - hence I have a similar problem and Guice is required in the test.  I'm sure that there are probably many other cases where Guice used in unit tests would be desirable.  Just my two cents..